# Apache-Kafka and python on smartphone, NoBrokerAvailable Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, termux

I have a question about some code in python that uses the kafka-python module and I really don't know why it doesn't work. After I initialize the Zookeeper&Kafka server with like the [quickstart page](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) suggests and creating at topic at my computer, I try to run the following code on my smartphone, using Termux:

```
from json import dumps, loads
from kafka import KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer

class CommunicationLayer:

def __init__(self, node_id):
self.output_publisher = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['192.168.1.103:9092'], value_serializer=lambda x:
dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

self.window_receiver = KafkaConsumer("node_{}".format(node_id), bootstrap_servers=['192.168.1.103:9092'] , value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
...
(code  that doesn't really help)
...
```

(The IP points to the machine that runs the kafka server). As soon as I run this code, I get NoBrokerAvailable error which, as far as I know, comes up only when you haven't initialized the servers. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to run the following code on my smartphone

Note: Kafka clients aren't intended to be ran in such environments where network connection is unreliable.

---

> The IP points to the machine that runs the kafka server

Is **ZooKeeper** as well as Kafka exposed **externally** on this machine and not only listening locally?

Similarly, you need to set the `advertised.listeners` property in Kafka properties to be this external address for any clients to be able to actually connect after the bootstrap connection.

Comment: Damn, I should really study the documentation more. Thanks, that worked out!